# USB Touch Screen Input device not recognised

Tags: android, usb, touch, multi-touch

Added support for my LG 17MB15T USB Touch screen to hid-ids.h and hid-multitouch.c and recompiled kernel. Device is recognised in DMESG and claimed by hid-multitouch :

```
<6>[  307.451668] usb 3-1.6: new full-speed USB device number 7 using sw-ehci
<6>[  307.563695] usb 3-1.6: New USB device found, idVendor=16fd, idProduct=d091
<6>[  307.563753] usb 3-1.6: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
<6>[  307.563803] usb 3-1.6: Product: LG TS2009F-USB
<6>[  307.563842] usb 3-1.6: Manufacturer: Edamak
<6>[  307.582868] input: Edamak LG TS2009F-USB as /devices/platform/sw-ehci.2/usb3/3-1/3-1.6/3-1.6:1.0/input/input8
<6>[  307.588181] hid-multitouch 0003:16FD:D091.0006: input: USB HID v1.11 Mouse
 [Edamak LG TS2009F-USB] on usb-sw-ehci-1.6/input0
```

Getevent -l Lists the device as an input device:

```
add device 1: /dev/input/event2
  name:     "Edamak LG TS2009F-USB"
add device 2: /dev/input/event5
  name:     "sun7i-ir"
could not get driver version for /dev/input/mouse0, Not a typewriter
add device 3: /dev/input/event1
  name:     "axp20-supplyer"
add device 4: /dev/input/event0
  name:     "sw-keyboard"
could not get driver version for /dev/input/mice, Not a typewriter
```

However no events are fired from it. 
My /system/usr/idc/Vendor_16fd_Product_d091.idc looks like this:

```
touch.deviceType = TouchScreen
touch.orientationAware = 1
device.internal = 0
keyboard.layout = qwerty
keyboard.characterMap = qwerty2
keyboard.orientationAware =1
keyboard.builtIn = 1
cursor.mode = navigation
cursor.orientationAware = 1
```

`dumsys input` does not list the device at all. Ive tried `touch.deviceType = Pointer` as well - no luck!

However if I load the stock kernel (Allwiner A20) Linux 3.4, Adroid 4.2.2, the device is detected as :

```
gen-usb 0003:16FD:D091.0006: input: USB HID v1.11 Mouse
```

And events are fired when touching or pressing on the screen. 
Dumsys input still does not recognise the device.

Im suspecting some issue with the .idc file but cant find much information on the properties and their legal values. Alternately there may be another intermediate file required to make it work.

The touchscreen works ok on Linaro 12 on the same hardware (pcduino 3), Windows 7, 8 on other hardware.

Your help and advise will be appreciated.